# Google app engine with custom domain shows redirected URLs

Tags: domain, redirect, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine with custom domain. (Flexible type with nodejs)

When I completed settings it with
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl?hl=en
, I could visit my site with custom domain "mydomain.com"

It's good. However, the problem is that URL address in my browser shows redirected URLs such as : "myGAEdomain.appspot-preview.com"

How can I get the address "mydoamin.com" in the browser URL address bar when I visited my GAE site ?
Or which part should I have to check to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You’re right, the App Engine Flexible Environment is currently in Beta as stated on the [official page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) and its implementation may change, possibly in backward-incompatible ways.

Now, in order to use Custom Domains with a Flexible Environment GAE instance, you first need to whitelist them prior adding them for your application as mentioned in this Before you Begin [section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#before_you_begin). Listed in the third point, it is possible to whitelist the domains by filling out this Google contact [form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/gae_flex_custom_domain).

Note that prior using any custom domains, all GAE instance's traffic is served from the `appspot-preview.com` domain as described in the Domain Update [section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/upgrading#domain_update). Therefore, it is possible that you were initialy able to map `yourdomain.com` to `YourProjectID.appspot-preview.com` and so, presumably having your `ProjectID` the same as `yourdomain` name would explain the behavior you noticed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is the report about what I did and how it's going.

I mailed Google with this issue and they resolved this problem in 2 days.
I'm not sure if this should be resolved by Google only, however, the menu was slightly changed after my request. I cannot see detailed domain setting any more. I think Google App Engine Flex is on Beta service now and the domain thing is still on development.